# Send AT commands via serial port using bash script on minimal linux

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port

I need to init, with AT commands, a mobile modem without external libraries using only bash on minimal BusyBox. The mobile modem is on a serial port.

It s working well with python but in case of python issues, the device should be still connected. That's why I want to use bash script.

Comment: What have you tried, what worked, where are you stuck? You can use `stty` to set baud rate etc., and just read and write from `/dev/ttyS1` etc. like from any normal file, using redirections etc.

Comment: all I needed was stty ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**stty cheatsheet :**

To get current configuration :

```
stty -F /dev/ttymxc0
```

To change baudrate of port to 115200 :

```
stty -F /dev/ttymxc0 115200
```

Write data to serial port :

```
echo "HELLO" > /dev/ttymxc0
```

Read data from serial port :

```
cat /dev/ttymxc0
```

To get statistics on serial port:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/<driver_name>
```